# Linear Algebra - complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $w = a + bi$ be a complex number and let $T : \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be defined by $T (z) = w \cdot z$. Considering $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$, find the matrix $B$ representing $T$ relative to the basis $\{1, i\}$ of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying $T$ on the basis:

$$T(1)=w=a\cdot 1+b\cdot i=(a,b)$$

and $$T(i)=w\cdot i=(a+bi)\cdot i=a\cdot i -b\cdot 1=(-b,a).$$

So $$T=\begin{pmatrix}a & -b \\ b &a\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Note that the matrices of this form provide a concrete construction of the complex numbers.